# How can i fix NumberFormatException?

Tags: java

I know this error is caused by a number format exception but i don't know how to fix it. i'v tried to do a function to Check if the variable is a Number or String
and here is my code

```
public boolean checkNumber(String x) {
   try{
       Integer.parseInt(x);
       return true;
   }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
       return false;
   }
}
```

and this is a function takes a parameter of format dd/mm/yyyy,
split and store it in an array, then call the previous function to determine if all index are integer number or not.

```
public boolean CheckBirthDate(String birthdate){
    int B = 0;
    String Line = birthdate;
    String[] seprated = Line.split("/");
    if( checkNumber(seprated[0])  && checkNumber(seprated[1])  && checkNumber(seprated[2])) {
        B = 1;
    }
    if(seprated.length == 3 && Integer.parseInt(seprated[0]) <= 31  && Integer.parseInt(seprated[1]) <=   12 && Integer.parseInt(seprated[2]) >= 1950 &&  Integer.parseInt(seprated[2]) <= 2017 && B == 1){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which operation throws the exception?  What is the string value you're trying to parse as an int?  Also, you should really take a look at `int.TryParse()` for testing if a value can be parsed.  It's generally preferred to using exceptions for checking that.

Comment: You need to put your `B == 1` condition at the beginning of the if statement so that it gets tested before you start doing your Integer.parseInt operations. Or even better: Just do a `return false;` if on of the checkNumber tests returns false and get rid of your B variable altogether.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS its all connected via `&&` so every condition will be tested no matter what

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: Not really, if he puts it at the beginning and `B == 1` returns false everything else is skipped because of short circuiting. Because False && whatever is allways false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a DateFormat?

```
String birthday = "25/05/1973";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
try {
    Date date = format.parse(birthday);
    System.out.println("date = " + date);
}
catch (ParseException e) {
     //date was bad format
}
```

Result:

```
date = Fri May 25 00:00:00 CET 1973
```

Comment: Example please? If I enter the date "25/05/AA", I get a java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "25/05/AA"

Comment: if i entered the date 12/12/F1999 I get a java.text.ParseException,but if i entered 12/12/1999F I do not get anything

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
public boolean CheckBirthDate(String birthdate) {
    int B = 0;
    String Line = birthdate;
    String[] seprated = Line.split("/");
    if (checkNumber(seprated[0]) && checkNumber(seprated[1]) && checkNumber(seprated[2])) {
        B = 1;
    }
    if (B == 1 && seprated.length == 3 && Integer.parseInt(seprated[0]) <= 31 && Integer.parseInt(seprated[1]) <= 12
        && Integer.parseInt(seprated[2]) >= 1950 && Integer.parseInt(seprated[2]) <= 2017) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is, that you check if `B == 1` at the end of the if-clause and not the beginning. Therefore java tries to parse the Integer, even though it hasn't verified that it is actually a number yet.

I would also use a boolean vor `B` instead of an int. But generally speaking SurfMan's solution is probably the best and prettiest

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to debug in order to figure out where the error ocurs.

Any way, the last conditional, I suggest you to change the order. You first check if strings are numbers, thats perfect, then you store the result in a variable, fine. The thing is that the way conditionals work could be the problem here.
You check whether are numbers or not at the end, and should be done at the begining, like:

```
if (B == 1 && seprated.length == 3 && Integer.parseInt(seprated[0]) <= 31 && Integer.parseInt(seprated[1]) <= 12
        && Integer.parseInt(seprated[2]) >= 1950 && Integer.parseInt(seprated[2]) <= 2017) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

This way first checks the first conditional, and if it is false, it doesnt keep doing the other conditions because  false & true  is always false